# How do I obtain the Gtk3 selection color of a widget using GtkStyleContext

Tags: python, gtk, gio

I'm trying to obtain the selection color of a Gtk3 IconView in python but I'm confused how to interpret the existing C++ documentation and how it relates to Python.

My current python code is as follows:

```
color = self.iconview.get_style().bg[Gtk.StateType.SELECTED]
```

This works ok in Ubuntu 12.04 - Gnome/Gtk 3.2 I think.

However the documentation here says `get_style` is deprecated since 3.0

- http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-style

In Ubuntu 12.10 which uses the latest GTK, the above does not work - I get an error:

```
CRITICAL **: StackOverflow protection.  Can't copy array element into GIArgument
```

The document says I should use GtkStyleContext - but how?

Can anyone give me a concrete python example?

Comment: It says "use GtkStyleContext" instead. gtk_widget_get_style_context seems to return the StyleContext for a Widget. gtk_style_context_get_background_color seems to return the background color for a given state. One of the states is named GTK_STATE_FLAG_SELECTED. Note that I just hacked this together in 1min without ever having worked with theming/styles in GTK before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C:

```
GdkRGBA color;
GtkStyleContext *style =
    gtk_widget_get_style_context(iconview);
gtk_style_context_get_background_color
    (style, GTK_STATE_FLAG_SELECTED, &color);
```

Python translation by fossfreedom:

```
context = self.iconview.get_style_context()
color = context.get_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.SELECTED)
```

It appears that the `GtkStyle` struct from gtk2 was simply replaced with the more modern `GtkStyleContext` class in gtk3

Answer (score 1):

The new answer is "you don't". There isn't necessarily a single background color any more.

Per the documentation of https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-get-background-color:

"This function is far less useful than it seems, and it should not be used in newly written code. CSS has no concept of "background color", as a background can be an image, or a gradient, or any other pattern including solid colors."

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would somehow also work for the IconView. You can use `Gtk.StyleContext().lookup_color(name)` (https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.lookup_color), which works for various colors of the theme

Here is an example

- code with fallback mechanism: https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/blob/024498109e3817738f3076ed73bd0cd94ad9bf05/inputremapper/gui/components/editor.py#L945
- those names can also be used in css files: https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/blob/e22d13832376e3a2dd6b753087e436b3ce94d80b/data/style.css#L28
- pictures: https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/pull/484#issuecomment-1279695258

The names you see in the code are extracted from the `/usr/share/themes` folder, searching for `@define-color` statements

To my knowledge this doesn't use any deprecated function.